# Coin game. How to make a player lose their next turn if they meet a certain criteria

Tags: java

I'm currently making a program that has 4 players taking turns tossing 3 coins. The first player to earn 16 points wins. A player earns points each time he tosses the coins. The number of points he earns equals to the number of heads he tosses. If he tosses **no heads then he loses his next turn**. If he flips 3 heads then he earns an extra turn and tosses the coins again. If he tosses less than 3 heads then it is the next player’s turn. A player must earn exactly 16 points to win. If a player has 14 points and tosses 2 heads then he wins but if he tosses n heads and **goes over 16 points then he loses half of his points and loses his turn too.** He must have exactly 16 points to win.

How do I get the player to be skipped for the next turn? Each player currently goes in order. Ex. Tom, Hank, Hannah, Tina. If hank rolls 0 heads or goes over 16 points he should lose he next turn making the order Tom, Hannah, Tina, Tom, Hank, Hannah, Tina. I've posted my code and I need to figure out how to edit the nextPlayer() method to suit my needs. I believe the logic and code I did in the computerState() method is correct for LOSE_TURN. Any help would be appreciated.

**Game Class**

```
import java.util.Random;

    public class Game
    {
      private Random randomizer;
      private final int n_players;
      private final int m_coins;
      private final int p_points;
      private int player_index;
      private boolean game_over;

      public Game()
      {
        n_players = 4;
        m_coins = 3;
        p_points = 16;
        game_over = false;
        randomizer = new Random();
        player_index = randomizer.nextInt(n_players);
      }

      public Game(int new_m_coins, int new_n_players, int new_p_points)
      {
          n_players = new_n_players;
          m_coins = new_m_coins;
          p_points = new_p_points;
          game_over = false;
          randomizer = new Random();
          player_index = randomizer.nextInt(n_players);
      }

      public int getPlayerIndex()
      {
          return player_index;
      }

      public void setPlayerIndex()
      {
          player_index = randomizer.nextInt(n_players);
      }

      public boolean gameOver()
      {

          return game_over;

      }

      public int nextPlayer(Player[] players)
      {
          //player_index = (player_index + 1) % n_players;

          if(players[player_index].getState() == State.EXTRA_TURN)
          {
             players[player_index].setState(State.NORMAL);
          }
          else if(players[player_index].getState() == State.LOSE_TURN)
          {
              player_index = (player_index + 1) % n_players;

          }
          else
          {
              player_index = (player_index + 1) % n_players;
          }

          /*while(players[player_index].getState() != State.NORMAL)
          {
              players[player_index].setState(State.NORMAL);
              player_index = (player_index + 1) % n_players;
          }*/
          return player_index;
      }
      public void computeState(Player player, int m_heads, int oldPoints, int newPoints)
      {

            int player_points = player.getPoints();

            if(player_points == p_points)
                game_over = true;
            else if(player_points > p_points)
            {
                player.setPoints(player_points / 2);
                player.setState(State.LOSE_TURN);
            }
            else if(m_heads == 0)
            {
                player.setState(State.LOSE_TURN);
            }
            else if(m_heads == 3)
            {
                player.setState(State.EXTRA_TURN);
            }
            else if(m_heads == 3 && player_points > p_points)
            {
                player.setState(State.NORMAL);
            }
            else
                player.setState(State.NORMAL);

      }
    }
```

**TestCoinGame**

```
public class testcoingame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     try
     {
      int m_coins = 3;
      int n_players = 4;
      int p_points = 16;
      String [] names = {"Hank", "Tina", "Hannah", "Tom"};
      Player [] players = new Player[n_players];

      for(int index = 0; index < players.length; index++)
        players[index] = new Player(names[index]);

      Coins coins = new Coins();
      Game game = new Game();
      int player_index;
      do
      {
          player_index = game.nextPlayer(players);
          System.out.printf("It is %s's turn\n", players[player_index].getName());
          System.out.printf("%s has %d points\n", players[player_index].getName(),
          players[player_index].getPoints());

          coins.tossCoins();
          int n_heads = coins.getNHeads();
          System.out.printf("%s tossed %d heads\n",
          players[player_index].getName(), n_heads);

          int old_points = players[player_index].getPoints();
          int new_points = old_points + n_heads;
          players[player_index].setPoints(new_points);
          game.computeState(players[player_index], n_heads, old_points, new_points);
          System.out.printf("%s has %d points\n", players[player_index].getName(),players[player_index].getPoints());
       }
      while(!game.gameOver());
      System.out.printf("%s wins!\n", players[player_index].getName());
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could start by commenting you code; using comments to "hide" code or that are exact duplicates of used code don't count.

Comment: To explain the downvotes you are receiving: your question demands more than 5 minutes of dedication. This exceeds the SO's typical threshold, so we downvote and move on.

Comment: Seems homework like in nature as well which might make people less likely to help unless you say it out right and ask a small question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a boolean instance variable in the `Player Class` that keeps track of whether the player skips her next turn.  When you get to the point of checking if that value is true or false and it evaluate to true (ie yes, she skips her turn), then skip what you would normally do for a turn, but set the boolean to false before you move on to the next `Player` or `Turn` or what have you.

EDIT (based on user response):
Pseudocode:
I'm assuming that you're keeping track of whose turn it would be via an array or list or something comparable to that.  I'm going to refer to that as playerList.  If, for example, we have three players, then we would keep looping on `playerList[0]`,`playerList[1]`,`playerList[2]`.

```
while (gameNotOver())
{
    if (!playerList[currentPlayer].skipNextTurn())
    {
        //do what you would normally do
    }
    else
    {
        playerList[currentPlayer].setSkipNextTurn(false);
    }
}
```